# Redundent Page Numbering in Table of Contents

Tags: latex

In my table of contents, the abstract and the table of contents have the same page number. The numbering of the summary is correct as II, but the table of contents must be III. However, I don't understand where the error is or why Overleaf doesn't recognize that my table of contents continues at III. Can someone please give me some advice?
Attached you can see a picture of how it looks.[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    \input{02_abstract}

    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter
    \Blinddocument 

    \backmatter
    \Blinddocument
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. We don't have access to your included files.

Answer (score 0):

Add \newpage in between Abstract block.

```
\newpage 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\input{02_abstract}

\newpage
```

Comment: `\newpage` might be OK in this context but `\clearpage` (and its sibling `\cleardoublepage`) are high level macros in LaTeX that issue `\newpage` under the hood and should be used instead. You can search [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for more info on that.